# How to change Android startup activity in a THOROUGH way?

Tags: android

I've seen the various other Android posts that talk about editing the part of the XML file that determines the main activity. But this simple solution isn't working for me at all, presumably because I'm trying to change the main activity in a large app, and the resulting loose ends leads to a ton of bugs.

In addition to changing the startup activity, I've also added an activity tag for the ex-startup activity that is replacing it. But I don't know which changes I should add to deal with the Fragments that are messed up by the startup activity change.

I'm getting this error:

```
  /AndroidRuntime(  741): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c for fragment PlaceholderFragment{42894810 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
```

Would appreciate any help.

Edit: I have also changed my layout settings to correspond to the fragment layout instead of the activity layout. I also made it so that the new activity extended Activity instead of ActionBarActivity. Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not used PlaceHolderFragment that was automatically added when a new project was created. You must have edited the fragment_main xml file and try to use findviewby id in your MainActivity oncreate method. The new update to adt has many people making this simple mistake.